# apt-get install insists on removing a package I don't want removed!

Tags: apt, software-installation, php, postfix

```
  sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dbconfig-common php5 php5-fpm php5-pgsql wwwconfig-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  php5-pgsql
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  php5-mysql postfixadmin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php5-mysqlnd php5-pgsql
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 2 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 186 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,858 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
```

I don't want postfixadmin removed.  How do I install mysqlnd (to get PHP and MariaDB to get along) without apt-get removing postfixadmin?

Thanks!

Comment: Run `sudo apt-mark manual postfixadmin` and then check..

Comment: postfixadmin was already set to manually installed.

After that, apt-get behaves the same way.

Comment: `postfixadmin` depends on `php5-pgsql` which is about to be removed.  Make sure you keep that too; then things should work.

Comment: Thanks, @tripleee.  Adding php5-pgsql as a first step seems to have solved it.

Comment: Will post that as an answer then; appreciate if you mark it as accepted (which will award me some points, but also mark this question as no longer in need of an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`postfixadmin` depends on `php5-pgsql` which is about to be removed. Make sure you keep that too; then things should work.

Comment: Doesn't work. In my case all packages listed under `The following packages will be REMOVED` are set to manual and it still insists on removing them.

Comment: I can't repro on Ubuntu 20.04 so it's a bit hard to recommend anything. If upgrading Ubuntu is not an option, try `apt-get install php5-pgsql postfixadmin` or try holding `postfixadmin`.